# Location header wrong after HTTP POST?

Tags: http, post, curl, resteasy, jersey-2.0

please forgive me if I do something terribly wrong, I shall correct it at once).

I'm creating a RESTservice and I need the location of the created resources, both for testing purposes and for further development.

As far is I have understood from the rfc 2616, the location header that I get back after a HTTP POST should give me at link to the resource I have created.

> 14.30 Location
>
> The Location response-header field is used to redirect the recipient
>      to a location other than the Request-URI for completion of the
>      request or identification of a new resource. For 201 (Created)
>      responses, the Location is that of the new resource which was created
>      by the request. For 3xx responses, the location SHOULD indicate the
>      server's preferred URI for automatic redirection to the resource. The
>      field value consists of a single absolute URI.
>
> ```
>   Location       = "Location" ":" absoluteURI
> ```
>
> An example is:
>
> ```
>   Location: http://www.w3.org/pub/WWW/People.html
> ```
>
> [link to rfc 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)

However, when I POST to create a new resource (for example with curl, but I tried different clients) as such:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><participant><first-name>Severinus</first-name><email>severinus@gmail.com</email></participant>" -v http://localhost:8080/VCTAserverFirstTest/services/participants
```

This is the header I get back:

> upload completely sent off: 133 out of 133 bytes
>   HTTP/1.1 201 Created
>   Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
>   Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
>   Location: `http://localhost:8080/participants/1`
>   Content-Length: 0
>   Date: Sat, 19 Apr 2014 16:07:31 GMT
>
> Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

Here the Location is `http://localhost:8080/participants/1` but the resources is in fact accessed on `http://localhost:8080/VCTAserverFirstTest/services/participants/1`

This is not what I expected. Do you need the server side code or is there an obvious answer to this?

Thanks
Lars

EDIT: Not a good answer for anybody else, but it was solved by using the resteasy framework.

Comment: Showing some relevant code would help us help you. Also mention the  REST framework you are using.

Comment: Thanks Bogdan. That actually let me to a solution, though I'm afraid I can't say exactly what was wrong. I was using the jersey framework. Then I tried RestEasy and it suddenly worked. Still I was probably doing something wrong with jersey because it should work. For me, for now, it is solved. Thanks again.